# Android higher build target can run on lower platform device?

Tags: android

I found that I can build the android apk with higher sdk target (let say 3.0) but I am still able to run my app in lower device (let say 2.1). May I know why? Only when I set the `android:minSdkVersion` to specific number still stop the execution.

Does it make sense that if I use some latest feature like Fragment in my app but run it in a lower platform device, if I do like that, what will happen to my app? Will my app crash?

I realize this when dealing with admob because I compile it in Android 4.1 but able to run it in device 2.1, this really amazes me.

Comment: you can always use the super awesome [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html)

Answer (score 2):

In order to work with Fragment in device with sdk lower than 3.0 you have to include the Android Support v4 Library as Referenced Library. This allows you to use Fragment and other feature introduced with the newest sdk released by Android. It's very important mantain retro compatibility with older Android devices, because of the yet too much diffusion of that devices.

For some references about the Android Support v4 Library you can check:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html

and this:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Without that, you can't use Fragment in sdk lower than 3.0 ( API Level 11 ).

Comment: hi guy, this sentence is conflited, I cannot figure out why:

**1.Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13). 
2.The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires a run-time of Android 1.5 or later (set android:minSdkVersion to at least 3 in your AndroidManifest.xml). This means you can develop with the latest version of the Android SDK and your app will still run on an earlier Android version (1.5 minimum). **


Why I build it at 3.2 but still able to run in 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

With your *AndroidManifest.xml* and using the declarative to declare the minimum and the target SDK version, your apk should run accordingly to the minimum SDK version:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="14">
```

Comment: hi guy, this sentence is conflited, I cannot figure out why:
<br/>
**1.Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13). 
2.The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires a run-time of Android 1.5 or later (set android:minSdkVersion to at least 3 in your AndroidManifest.xml). This means you can develop with the latest version of the Android SDK and your app will still run on an earlier Android version (1.5 minimum). **
<br/>

Why I build it at 3.2 but still able to run in 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

May I know why?

it is due to `android:minSdkVersion`

use

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

Does it make sense that if I use some latest feature like Fragment in my app but run it in a lower platform device, if I do like that, what will happen to my app? Will my app crash?

It will crash when it uses a new SDK feature that is not present in the older platform.

Answer (score 0):

> I found that I build the android apk with higher sdk target (let say
>   3.0) but I am still able to run my app in lower device (let say 2.1). May I know why?

Thats how android SDK works. But by default when u create an Android Project in Eclipse, and select SDK version to be say, 3.0, ADT will automatically set android:minSdkVersion to 11. If you dont want to run you app on version less than 3.0, dont change this value.

> Does it make sense that if I use some latest feature like Fragment in
>   my app but run it in a lower platform device, if I do like that, what
>   will happen to my app? Will my app crash?

Definitely it'll crash. You'll get method not found exception. Instead u can use a library that is supported on both lower and higher versions of android like [fragments for all](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html)

Comment: hi guy, this sentence is conflited, I cannot figure out why:
<br/>
**1.Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13). 
2.The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires a run-time of Android 1.5 or later (set android:minSdkVersion to at least 3 in your AndroidManifest.xml). This means you can develop with the latest version of the Android SDK and your app will still run on an earlier Android version (1.5 minimum). **
<br/>

Why I build it at 3.2 but still able to run in 1.5?

Comment: there two different properties of Android Project. One You can see in default.properties `target=android-xx`. ADT uses this android version to compile you project. In you project's manifest file you have another property `android:minSdkVersion=yy` this one is used to determine what is the least supported android version for your project. set same `xx` and `yy` in your project to remove the warning that u're getting.